# XCode 4 : Why does it fill all the view?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, fill

Simple question, I think.
Whenever I add an object like, a button for example, in my View Controller, in the Storyboard, it fills all the screen of the device. Can't figure out why.

Any advices ?

Comment: Check  autoresize stuff for both view and parent view.

Comment: How are you adding the button?

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding UIButton to the UIViewController directly, right ?
You first need to add a UIView on the controller and then add objects to that view.